# How to find documents where field1 is greater than field2? ( Nodejs/Mongoose/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How do you use values from fields in comparison when executing queries?

Example from docs:

`db.inventory.find( { qty: { $gt: 20 } } )`

How can I use a field value from the document instead of 20, like so:

`db.inventory.find( { qty: { $gt: field2 } } )`

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var query = model.find();

var first = "field1";
var second = "field2";

query.where(first).gt(second);
```

Edit: I am building the query dynamicly, so I need to use the query-builder in mongoose.

Edid2: Thanks to the answer below, this is how I solved my problem:

```
query.where({$where: "this."+first+" > this."+second});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below query with $WHERE operator :

```
 db.inventory.find({$where: function() { 
  return ( this.field1 >   this.field2 ); } });
```

P.S : you can find the $Where documnetation in below link :
    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: I see, thank you. But how do I create the query using the query builder?
I am creating multiple queries from dynamic settings, I tried this without luck:

query.where(first+" < "+second);

Comment: or this `$where: "this.field1 > this.field2"`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this solved my problem:

query.where({$where: "this."+first+" > this."+second});